# Gigabit ethernet switch with VLAN management powered thru PoE

Tags: switch

I'm shopping for a Gigabit Ethernet switch

1. With remote administration allowing assigning VLAN to downstream ports ("Layer2+")
2. Powered over Ethernet by the upstream link (no power cord or adapter). PoE pass-through not required.
3. With 1 upstream, at least 4 downstream ports (7 or 8 ideal)
4. Most preferably, rack-mountable

Lacking 2, there is the [TL-SG1016DE](https://www.tp-link.com/en/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg1016de/).

Update: Lacking 4, the [DGS-1100-05PDV2](https://eu.dlink.com/us/en/-/media/business_products/dgs/dgs-1100/datasheet/dgs_1100_v2_datasheet_en_eu.pdf).

---

Final update: thanks to the accepted answer, I checked the PoE out capability of the device (an RB1100AHX4 router) that was supposed to power my switch thru it's upstream port. Turns out this has PoE in but not PoE out, as I was told. My whole plan thus can not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco [C3560CX-8PT-S](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3560-cx-series-switches/datasheet-c78-733229.html) has remote management, up to two PoE upstream power sources, 8 ports, wall and rack mountable. You can power with a single PoE+ upstream or two PoE upstream.

They are readily available on eBay for reasonable prices now.

Comment: Reading the line in table 3 of the page you link that reads "C3560CX-8PT-S / 1 PoE uplink / 0W / No", when powered by a single upstream port, that needs to be PoE+ rather than just PoE. I'd have to check that the upstream PoE source (RB1100AHX4) can supply the required power. If not, I'm thinking of DGS-1100-05PDV2 and a makeshift mounting in a rack.

Comment: Oups, checking the PoE out capability of said RB1100AHX4: it has none, contrary to what I was told!! So I must throw out the whole idea. That solves the problem, albiet not as expected. Many thanks.

Comment: Run two PoE, that’s how I run one of them in my closet with a patch panel.